# Mysql DOUBLE column data truncated exception using Java Double

Tags: java, mysql, double, floating-point-precision, double-precision

I have a MySQL table with a Double datatype column, when I insert the value contained in a Java Double I always get a truncation error.

> Mrz 19, 2015 11:26:00 AM databaseimport.MyImport executeQuery
>   SCHWERWIEGEND: null java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column
>   'SHARE' at row 1

I tried changing column to a higher precision with DOUBLE PRECISION(30,30) which seems the maximum for the DOUBLE but the error remains.

Here sample snippet:

```
Double share = (Double) shareRow.get("share");

sql = ("INSERT INTO `SHARE_VALUES` (`ID`, `SHARE`)" +
       "VALUES (NULL, "+share+");");
try
        {
            // Create a Preparedstatement
            PreparedStatement ps;
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            ps.execute();
            ResultSet generatedKeys = ps.getGeneratedKeys();

        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Shares.class
                    .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            return -1;
        }
```

Comment: please provide a snipped of the java code of the insert/update statement....

Comment: What size does the SHARE column allow?

Comment: Would expect `DOUBLE(30, 15)` to work for say `1.5`. Try things out in a mysql console, workbench, Toad, or IDE SQL console. I think the problem was for the space of integer digits, the mantissa.

Comment: Tried DOUBLE(30, 30) which is the maximum precision and still data is truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
sql = String.format(Locale.US, "INSERT INTO `SHARE_VALUES` (`ID`, `SHARE`)" +
       "VALUES (NULL, %.3f);", share);
```

When concatenating strings java might use your locale to turn, for example 6.80 into "6,80" <- the comma (',') sign has different meaning for MySQL and that may certainly cause a lot of problems.

If  you intend to use prepared statement, then this would be more like it:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());    
Double share = nf.parse(shareRow.get("share")).doubleValue();

sql = ("INSERT INTO `SHARE_VALUES` (`ID`, `SHARE`)" +
       "VALUES (NULL, ?);");
try
{
    // Create a Preparedstatement
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    ps.setDouble(1, share);
    ps.execute();
    ResultSet generatedKeys = ps.getGeneratedKeys();

}
catch (SQLException ex)
{
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Shares.class
            .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    return -1;
}
```

Note that the query string comes with "?" signs, these indicate parameters. When you call:

```
ps.setDouble(1, share);
```

that will specify that, parameter 1 value is `share`, thus the first "?" sign is replaced by the value of `share` (totally aware of java to mysql conversions and no issues with locale).